# Order by or where clause: which is effecient when retrieving a record from versioned table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This might be a basic sql questions, however I was curious to know the answer to this.

I need to fetch top one record from the db. Which query would be more efficient, one with where clause or order by?

Example:

Table

```
Movie
id    name isPlaying endDate isDeleted
```

Above is a versioned table for storing records for movie.

If the endDate is not null and isDeleted = 1 then the record is old and an updated one already exist in this table.

So to fetch the movie "Gladiator" which is currently playing, I can write a query in two ways:

```
1. 
    Select m.isPlaying
    From Movie m
    where m.name=:name (given)
    and m.endDate is null and m.isDeleted=0


2. Select TOP 1 m.isPlaying 
   From Movie m
   where m.name=:name (given)
   order by m.id desc --- This will always give me the active record (one which is not deleted)
```

Which query is faster and the correct way to do it?

Update:
id is the only indexed column and id is the unique key. I am expecting the queries to return me only one result.

Update:

Examples:

```
Movie
id   name        isPlaying EndDate       isDeleted
 3   Gladiator    1         03/1/2017      1
 4   Gladiator    1        03/1/2017       1
 5   Gladiator    0         null           0
```

Comment: I mean, you tell us which is faster. It's your system. Run each one a dozen times and benchmark. I would not rely on ordering to define whether a record has been deleted if you have a specific field for that purpose, though.

Comment: Why would you use `ORDER BY`????  You only select 1 row.

Comment: There is not right answer here based on the vague description. This requires knowledge of things like the table structure including indexes, how many rows in the table etc....but above all else @JacobH is absolutely correct. If you have a column to indicate a status why go around it by doing something odd like that. The rest of your logic seems quite off to me.

Comment: Is ID the primary key in the table? If so they are both wrong. You only need to find the one and only one row with the primary key value you are asking for. Any other predicates are redundant and ordering is pointless.

Comment: I agree, I found this issue myself while I was working with a friend on the project. The only indexed field is the name and its the primary key. I should have mentioned that. I will update the question

Comment: @SeanLange: Why is the first one wrong? They should both work actually.

Comment: It would work but why bother check endDate and isDeleted? You don't check those in the second query? The logic of finding rows is completely different in those two queries.

Comment: I have updated the query and added few more details

Comment: So you can get multiple rows for any given value of ID? I don't see how either of your queries satisfies the conditions. And again, they are very different in what they return. I think you should post your table definition and some sample data to clarify this question. This could go round and round for days.

Comment: I added sample data and update the query. Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to give an example which is not related to what I am currently working on but represents it. I misrepresented few things.

Comment: So now that you have sample data it should be very clear those two queries do NOT do the same thing. The first one gets ID = 4 but only if endDate is null and isDeleted = 0. The second query does not have those extra restrictions. But if you are saying you always pass in the "correct" value of 5, then why bother with the rest of it. Just get that row and move on.

Comment: For second query : But when I order by id in desc order and get the top 1, it should always return me the valid record right?

Comment: NO. You have different values for each row in ID right? What if in the row where ID = 5 the endDate = '20180101' and isDeleted = 1? The ordering query would return that row. The first query would not return a row at all.

Comment: ahh. I did not think about the condition when the given movie is not playing (no records to show). Thanks

Comment: Does not look like TSQL to me

Comment: @Eric, is not the same top 1 order by desc than top 1 order by asc

Comment: @JaimeDrq The query changed.  When I commented, the WHERE clause used `id` instead of `name`, and the `SELECT` didn't have `TOP 1`.  So my question was why used `ORDER BY` if there's only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the `where` clause:

```
Select m.isPlaying
From Movie m
where m.id = :id and m.endDate is null and m.isDeleted = 0;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(id, isDeleted, endDate)`.

Also, the two are not equivalent.  The second might return multiple rows when the first returns 1.  Or the second might return one row when the first returns none.

Comment: I am sorry, let me update the query. The query I suggested would return 1 for both

Answer (score 0):

The first option might return more than 1 row. Maybe you know it won't because you know what data you have stored but the SQL engine doesn't, and it will affect it's execution plan.

Considering that you only have 1 index and it's on the `ID` column, the 2nd query **should** be faster in theory, since it would do an index scan from the highest `ID` with a predicate for the given `name`, stopping at the first match.

The first query will do a full table scan while comparing column `name`, `endDate` and `isDeleted`, since it won't stop at the first result that matches.

Posting your execution plans for both queries might enlighten a few loose cables.